# How to generate JSON schema from a JAXB annotated class?

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson, jsonschema

I have a entity class looks like this.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class ImageSuffix {

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean canRead;

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean canWrite;

    @XmlValue;
    private String value;
}
```

And I'm using following dependency for JSON generation.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I tried with following code, (which referred from [Generating JSON Schemas with Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonSchemaGeneration))

```java
@Path("/imageSuffix.jsd")
public class ImageSuffixJsdResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String read() throws JsonMappingException {

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final JsonSchema jsonSchema =
            objectMapper.generateJsonSchema(ImageSuffix.class);

        final String jsonSchemaString = jsonSchema.toString();

        return jsonSchemaString;
    }
}
```

Server complains with following error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.googlecode.jinahya.test.ImageSuffix would not be serialized as a JSON object and therefore has no schema
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.generateJsonSchema(StdSerializerProvider.java:299)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.generateJsonSchema(ObjectMapper.java:2527)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.generateJsonSchema(ObjectMapper.java:2513)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI - We are currently adding this support to MOXy's JSON-binding.  You can track this work using the following link:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/404452

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried configuring your ObjectMapper to include jaxb introspector? We use spring mvc3 for implementing REST services and use the same model objects to serialize into xml/json.

```
AnnotationIntrospector introspector = 
    new Pair(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(), new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
objectMapper.generateJsonSchema(ImageSuffix.class);
```

**EDIT**: Here is the output I get from jackson:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "canRead" : {
      "type" : "boolean",
      "required" : true
    },
    "canWrite" : {
      "type" : "boolean",
      "required" : true
    },
    "value" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Btw, a small edit is made to your answer.

Comment: I believe this is actually incorrect JSON Schema. The correct output should not include 'required', and should show the third type as 'type: ["string","null"]' (i.e. a nullable type). Can Jackson be configured to produce this?

Comment: @asgs I guess a lot of changes have been done to `Jackson` till now and the things have been deprecated so this answer does not work for the current version of the `Jackson`. If possible can you please let me know how can it be done using the latest version of the `Jackson`? I have `JAXB/Moxy` annotated class from which I would like to generate `JSONSchema`.

Answer (score 1):

The provided answer is a bit old and some of the things have been deprecated now. So try the following code with the latest `Jackson` and `JAXB/Moxy` annotated classes:

Approach-1

```
class JsonSchemaGenerator{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);

    //To force mapper to include JAXB annotated properties in Json schema
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    objectMapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(objectMapper.constructType(Customer.class), visitor);

    JsonSchema inputSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
    String schemaString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inputSchema);

    System.out.println(schemaString);
  }

}
```

Approach -2 :

```
class JsonSchemaGenerator{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);
    final JsonSchema jsonSchema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(Class.forName("com.jaxb.Customer"));
    System.out.println(jsonSchema);
  }
}
```